# 2-transitivity, action of $GL_2(\mathbb{R})$ on the projective space

Tags: group-theory, linear-transformations

If $G$ is a group and $X$ a set with cardinality $\geqslant 2$, we call the action of $G$ on $X$ 2-transitive if the action of $G$ on $X\times X-\Delta$  (all couples off the diagonal) is transitive.

> I have to show that being 2-transitive is equivalent to $X\times X$ having two orbits under the product action of $G$.
>
> Then I have to show that the action of $GL_2 (\mathbf{R})$ on $\mathbf{P}^1(\mathbf{R})$ (lines in $\mathbf{R}^2$) is 2-transitive.

For the first one, I know that $gx=gy \iff x=y$ so $G$ acts separately on $X\times X-\Delta$ and $\Delta$. It remains to show that $G$ acts transitively on $\Delta$. I do not see why this is true. It seems to me that $\Delta$ can be the disjoint union of orbits..

For the second question, it is clear that $GL_2 (\mathbf{R})$ acts transitively on $\mathbf{P}^1(\mathbf{R})$. However, given a line $\ell$, why do we always have a linear transformation that sends one line to another fixing $\ell$?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the action is $2$-transitive. We are going to show that there exists $2$ orbits, the diagonal $\Delta$ and $X\times X-\Delta$.

Let $x,y$ in $X$ with $x\neq y$, there exists $g$ such that $g.(x,y)=(y,x)$ this implies tha $g.x=y$ and $g.(x,x)=(y,y)$ and the diagonal is an orbit.

Suppose that there exists $2$ orbits.
Let $x\neq y$, $(x,x)$ and $(x,y)$ are not in the same orbit. For any $a,b\in X$, either  $(a,b)$ is in the orbit of $(x,x)$ or in in the orbit of $(x,y)$. Suppose that $a=b$, $g.(a,a)=(g.a,g.a)\neq (x,y)$ implies that $(a,b)$ is in the orbit of $(x,x)$.

If $a\neq b, g.(a,b)=(g.a,g.b)\neq (x,x)$ implies that $(a,b)$ is in the orbit of $(x,y)$ and the action is transitive on $X\times X-\Delta$.

Let $l_1,l_2$ be two distinct lines, $u_1,u_2$ a generator of $l_1$ and $l_2$. The vectors $u_1,u_2$ are linearly independent since $l_1$ and $l_2$ are distinct. We can define the linear map $A(u_1)=u_2,A(u_2)=u_1$, we have $A(l_1)=l_2$ and $Gl_2(R)$ is a $2$-transitive action.